# jQuery hide one div show another

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the following website: http://driz.co.uk/taschen/

I'm wanting to make it so when a user clicks the toggle div the currently shown ipad is faded out and the other ipad is faded in. And vice-versa.

How do I do this using jQuery? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) to alternate between functions, like this:

```
$("#toggle").toggle(function() {
  $("#ipad-portrait").fadeOut(function() { $("#ipad-landscape").fadeIn(); });
}, function() {
  $("#ipad-landscape").fadeOut(function() { $("#ipad-portrait").fadeIn(); });
});
```

Or, using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (there are a few ways, this is one of them):

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
  var ipads = $("#ipad-portrait, #ipad-landscape"), 
      current = ipads.filter(":visible").fadeOut(function() {
                  ipads.not(current).fadeIn();
                });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#ipad-landscape, #ipad-portrait").toggle();
});
```

Aha, you want fading...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function added in jQuery **1.4.4** (You need to update to this version from the version 1.4.2 script you're using on that page):

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#ipad-portrait, #ipad-landscape').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: This won't have the desired effect, as both will be visible at the same time, causing a page scroll.

Comment: @NickCraver Ah, yes, that's what would usually happen. However, both iPads are AP'ed, so I got lucky this time. Will take note next time though.