# Another way to write javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's another more terse way to write the following. Basically it toggles the visibility of 2 button based on a condtion.

```
$("#myCheckBox").click(function() {
    if (window.console && window.console.log)
        console.log("billing only checked? " + this.checked);
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#btnNext").hide();
        $("#btnFinish").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#btnNext").show();
        $("#btnFinish").hide();
    }
});
```

Just looking for a more efficient way possibly?

Comment: You'll only get terser ways of writing it, which usually means "harder to read". Leave it as is - it's fine.

Comment: Is button finish hidden to begin with ? Event before clicking the checkbox ?

Comment: You should optimize for readability. Why do you think this isn't efficient enough?

Comment: Similar to [jQuery hide one div show another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467276/jquery-hide-one-div-show-another)

Comment: @ObscureRobot there's other JavaScript more important surrounding this. I think it would be easy enough to understand no matter how terse this particular case is.

Comment: Try telling that to your hung-over self at 2AM six months from now when an obscure bug hits the fan. (I've been there. It isn't much fun. Don't make it worse). Note - I'm taking issue with your request for "terse" code, which is often harder to read. A request for a more concise solution would produce more positive results. It is all about the question framing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which accepts an argument indicating whether an element should be shown or hidden:

```
$("#btnNext").toggle(!this.checked);
$("#btnFinish").toggle(this.checked);
```

If the visibility is correctly set up from the beginning, you don't even have to pass an argument:

```
$("#btnNext, #btnFinish").toggle();
```

---

I agree with others regarding readability though. `.toggle` by itself might be still understandable, but `.toggle(!this.checked)` can become more difficult to comprehend.

Comment: This is a great solution because it increases clarity while reducing code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the toggle() function - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$("#myCheckBox").click(function() {
    if (window.console && window.console.log)
        console.log("billing only checked? " + this.checked);
    $("#btnNext").toggle(!this.checked);
    $("#btnFinish").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this:

```
if (this.checked) {
    $("#btnNext").hide();
    $("#btnFinish").show();
}
else {
    $("#btnNext").show();
    $("#btnFinish").hide();
}
```

to this:

```
$("#btnNext").toggle(!this.checked);
$("#btnFinish").toggle(this.checked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they start in the correct `show` and `hide` states you can just do the following.

```
$("#myCheckBox").click(function() {
  if (window.console && window.console.log) {
    console.log("billing only checked? " + this.checked);
  }
  $("#btnNext").toggle();
  $("#btnFinish").toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of show/hide, then you could get rid of the if/else construct.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be 100% efficient - I'm sure you can condense this by using a clever ternary or something (Edit: Felix Kling has a nice one already) - *but* on the other hand, it is perfectly readable this way, even for a person who is not familiar with the project at all.

My tendency would be to leave it as it is.